# Eager loading entire association?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, eager-loading

Is there a way I can eager load an entire object graph with a grails `list()` domain method?

Right now, I specify

`MyObject.list(fetch:[assoc1:'eager'])`, but `assoc1`  has associations which must also be eagerly loaded. Is there an easy solution to eager load my entire object graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this in the Grails documentation.  It's not exactly using the list() method, however, it does keep you from having to specify eager in your domain classes so you can do eager fetching at will.  I still am not 100% sure if this will get what you want, but it is the closest thing I could find.

> Querying with Eager Fetching In the
>   section on Eager and Lazy Fetching we
>   discussed how to declaratively specify
>   fetching to avoid the N+1 SELECT
>   problem. However, this can also be
>   achieved using a criteria query:

```
def criteria = Task.createCriteria()
def tasks = criteria.list{
    eq "assignee.id", task.assignee.id
    join 'assignee'
    join 'project'
    order 'priority', 'asc'
}
```

Comment: It gets me closer, at least. +1 upvote for being helpful, and you get the accept unless someone comes along with a better answer.